# How are the visually similar images in Google Vision API retreived?

Tags: image, image-processing, google-cloud-platform, similarity, google-vision

I have retrieved "Visually Similar Images" using Google Vision API. I would like to know how given a photo (that could pertain to a blog or article), Google Vision API finds a list of visually similar images? I cannot seem to find a white paper describing this.

Additionally, I would like to know if it makes sense to consider these visually similar images if the labels predicted by Google Vision API have a score lower than 70% confidence?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision), Google Cloud’s Vision API offers powerful pre-trained machine learning models through REST and RPC APIs, like the [Web Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web) which are in charge of processing and analyzing the images received in order to identify other images with characteristics similar to the original, as is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/features-list#web-entities-and-pages-8); however, since it is a pre-trained model of Google there isn’t a public documentation of its development.

Regarding your question about considering a confidence score lower than 70%, it completely depends on your use-case, you have to evaluate the acceptance limits required in order to satisfy your requirements.

Please note that the object returned in the "visuallySimilarImages" field of the [JSON response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#webdetection) is a [WebImage object](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#webimage) and its score field is deprecated, you may be referring to the score within the [WebEntity object](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#webentity) that is an overall relevancy score for the entity. Not normalized and not comparable across different image queries.